# Laravel join with LIKE CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, left-join

**Laravel 5.1.11**

I have a simple search in my shop:

```
public function search($request $request)
{
        return Catalog::where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->searchQuery.'%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(50);
}
```

**This is worked!**

But people are looking for goods so: `Pump BOSCH`. And search result is null.

Because I changed my select:

```
public function search($request $request)
{
    $searchQ = preg_split('/\s+/', $request->searchQuery, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    return Catalog::where(function ($q) use ($searchQ) {
               foreach ($searchQ as $value) {
                   $q->orWhere('title', 'like', "%{$value}%");
               }
           })
           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
           ->paginate(50);
}
```

**And this is worked), and show all `Pumps`!**

But i want show only one `Pump bosch`.

My DB table `manufactories`:

```
|  id  | title  |
| :--: | :----- |
|   1  |  AlKO  |
|   2  |  BOSCH |
```

AND `catalogs`, where `m_id` is `id` from table `manufactory`:

```
|  id  |  m_id | title |     url    |
| :--: | :---: | :---- | :--------- |
|   1  |   1   |  pump | pump-alko  |
|   2  |   2   |  pump | pump-bosch |
```

> How do I change the MySQL search query (adding LEFT JOIN and CONCAT) to find `Pump bosch`?
>   To make it look like this: `CONCAT('catalogs.title', ' ', 'manufactories.title') LIKE '%'.$request->searchQuery.'%'`

Comment: That's the dilemma with simple searches - it's hard to predict what exactly a customer searches for. What if you change your query and then a customer looks for "pump siemens" and you dont happen to have siemens pumps. or he looks for "pump Aklo" (typo). I recommend you have a look at Laravel Scout and Algolia. This provides you with a very simple to use search solution and Algolia is free for smaller data sets https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout

Comment: user searches , so the result are from 0 to n numbers , you show them , what's the problem ? if you have n result of search then show the result

Comment: @mahdi-younesi I need a search in a bunch of two fields from different tables. LIke this `CONCAT('catalogs.title',  ' ', 'manufactories.title')` LIKE '%'.$request->searchQuery.'%'

Comment: @michel-feldheim Laravel 5.1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simply like this,

```
        $data = DB::table('manufactories')
            ->join('catalogs','manufactories.id','=','catalogs.m_id')
            ->select('manufactories.title','catalogs.title')
            ->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(manufactories.title," ",catalogs.title)'), 'like',"%{$value}%")
            ->get();
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you so much for accepting my answer brother. if it helpful to you do not forget to give it a upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) to do joins e.g.

```
DB::table('catalogs')
    ->select('catalogs.*')
    ->join('manufactories', 'catalogs.m_id', '=', 'manufactories.id', 'left')
    ->where(function($q) use ($searchQ) {
        foreach ($searchQ as $value) {
            $q->orWhere('manufactories.title', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('catalogs.title', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        }
    })
    ->get();
```